# Laravel Create a request internally Resolved

Tags: laravel

I need to recreate a resquest so that it behaves like a call via api to go through the validator, but my `$request->input('rps.number')` always arrives empty, although I can see the data in the debug

I also couldn't get it to go through the laravel validator

I can't use a technique to make an http call, because I need to put this call in a transaction

[image]

```
<?php

$nota = new stdClass();

$rps = new stdClass();
$rps->numero = (int)$xml->Rps->IdentificacaoRps->Numero;
$rps->serie = (string)$xml->Rps->IdentificacaoRps->Serie;
$rps->tipo = (int)$xml->Rps->IdentificacaoRps->Tipo;
$nota->rps = $rps;

$controller = new NotaController(new Nota());
$content = new StoreNotaRequest();
$content->request->add($nota);
$result = $controller->store($content);
```

StoreNotaRequest

```
<?php

class StoreNotaRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        $request = $this->request;

        return [

            'rps.numero' => 'required_with:rps|numeric|between:1,999999999999999',
            'rps.serie' => 'required_with:rps|string|min:1|max:5',
            'rps.tipo' => 'required_with:rps|integer|in:1,2,3'
        ];

    }
}
```

NotaController

```
<?php

class NotaController extends Controller
{
    private Nota $nota;


    public function __construct(Nota $nota)
    {
        $this->nota = $nota;
    }

    public function store(StoreNotaRequest $request): JsonResponse
    {

       // $validated = $request->validated();

        try {
            $nota = DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {
                 $request->input('rps.numero');
            });

            return response()->json($nota);
        } catch (Throwable $e) {
            return response()->json($data, 409);
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution**

the solution was a little too verbose, I believe it is possible to solve with less code.

more does what it needs to go through the validation of the data contained in the **StoreNotaRequest**
and it returns an http response, in addition to being able to put all these isolated calls in a single transaction

```
DB::beginTransaction();

$errors = [];

foreach ($itens as $item) {
 $controller = new NotaController(new Nota());
 $request = new StoreNotaRequest();
 $request->setMethod('POST');
 $request->request->add($nota);
 $request
        ->setContainer(app())
        ->setRedirector(app(Redirector::class))
        ->validateResolved();
 $response = $controller->store($request);

 if ($response->statusText() !== 'OK') {
  $errors[$item->id] = 'ERROR';
 }
}

if (count($errors) === 0) {
 DB::commit();
} else {
 DB::rollBack();
}
```

Comment: needed to add $content->setMethod('POST');, 
now I just need to make the method fire the validator automatically

Comment: Internal requests can be made using app()->handle() like this:

`$internalRequest = Request::create('/oauth/token', 'POST', $data, [], [] , $server);
$response = app()->handle($internalRequest);`

Comment: When running it directly like just calling the method yourself, as you did, you probaly miss middlewares and the form request validation stuff.